# Installing MariaDB on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mariadb

How can install MariaDb on ubuntu 14.04 , i have searched in Ubuntu Software Center but its not there. Then checked MariaDB official website but its clearly mentioned there are some issues in .deb file for ubuntu.

Can I download the .rpm file which is for redhat and then onvert it into .deb by using Alien command.

Would it be fine?

As mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes) . Ubuntu 14.04 LTS continues to provide official support for MySQL 5.5. Three other community supported alternatives of MySQL are also included:

```
MariaDB 5.5 - a drop in replacement for MySQL 5.5.
```